# Proving Lower bounds on an Approximately Linear Function

Tags: analysis, inequality, exponential-function, approximation, linear-approximation

We are looking for a lower bound on the function, $\frac{1.31}{e^{\frac{1.31}{x+1}} - 1}$ for $x \geq 2$. This function seems to behave linearly. We believe that the following statement holds:

$$\frac{1.31}{e^{\frac{1.31}{x+1}} - 1} > x,$$ but we have not been able to prove it thus far.

Any hints or insights would be greatly appreciated. Any other lower bounds would also be useful.

Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

$e^x \leq 1 + x + x^2$ for $x \leq 1$, so

$e^{\frac{1}{x+1}} \leq 1 + \frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$ for $x \geq 0$. Then

$e^{\frac{1}{x+1}} - 1 \leq \frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}$

and $x \leq \frac{1}{\frac{1}{x+1} + \frac{1}{(x+1)^2}} \leq \frac{1}{e^{\frac{1}{x+1}} - 1}$

Bad stuff happens when you introduce the 1.31; for $\alpha >= 1$ you'll end up with

$\frac{x}{\alpha^2} \leq \frac{1}{\frac{\alpha}{x+1} + \frac{\alpha^2}{(x+1)^2}} \leq \frac{1}{e^{\frac{\alpha}{x+1}} - 1}$

with $\alpha = 1.31$. So this method doesn't produce an inequality as tight as you want.

Answer (score 0):

As $x$ tends to infinity, the denominator of your expression (lets call it $f(x)$ ) goes to zero without ever being negative, so $f(x)\geq 0$ for all $x\geq 2$ and I hazard the guess that your function is monotone increasing.

The easiest way to show your assertion then is to show that the inequality holds at $x=2$, and then show that the derivative on the left side is always bigger than the derivative on the right side, which equals to $1$.

You can then bound 
$$f(2+t)\geq f(2)+t\cdot \inf_{t\geq 0} f'(2+t),$$ 
so if $\inf_{t\geq 0} f'(2+t)\geq 1$ this implies 
$$f(2+t)\geq f(2)+t \geq 2+t\quad \forall t\geq 0.$$